# How to find the a value is existing or not in sqlite3?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using sqlite database for android development.
I should not have the repeatation of records with a same username so that i need to check is that username is existing or not in the database.
For that i got a solution called count query.
Can i get how to use the count query in sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rawQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29), something like:

```
final String SQL_STATEMENT = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE uname=?";

private void someMethod() {
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(SQL_STATEMENT, new String[] { username });
    ...
}
```